# recording data played by multiple wave out devices

Tags: c++, c, windows

i have a program in which i receive voice data from multiple parties over socket and then
i play it using multiple objects of wave out in separate threads , i want to store data
into a common file like a conversation. possible?i am using windows MMI , waveout.

Comment: i have tried:1.static buffer for waveout object class which plays the data. Fill the buffer and write the buffer in a file at callback method which is called after ::WaveOutWrite().2.tried writing in a file using semaphore.3.tried directly writing in a file-this gives an file which when played plays with distortion like having gaps/digitized. the data is in pcm format and stored as such.i am wondering whether this can be saved in a file directly?suppose there are 2 clients whos data is received simultaneously over socket,there has to be some kind of mixing of before writing into the file?

Comment: should i use a timer implementation and buffer? fill buffer from point 1 and start timer - if data from point 2 comes before timeout mix data with buffer data and write in a file else write buffer data adn restart timer.